# Find the minimum index of a vector where the user input value is greater

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

```
Data:-

static_vector <- c(10,50,100,200,500,1000)
df <- data.frame(Id=c("A1","B1"),Value=c(5,200))

  Id Value
1 A1     5
2 B1   200

df$Position <-static_vector[which(df$Value<=static_vector)]

Error:-
replacement has 4 rows, data has 2

Expected Output:-

  Id Value Position
1 A1     5  1
2 B1   200  4
```

As you can see that Value for A1 (5) is less than or equal to the first element in the static vector and so I need Position value as 1. I tried using the **which** statement above but, it throws me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cut` function:

```
df$Position <- as.integer(cut(df$Value, breaks = c(0, static_vector)))
df
  Id Value Position
1 A1     5        1
2 B1   200        4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `which`,

```
df$Position <- sapply(df$Value, function(i) min(which(i <= static_vector)))
df
#  Id Value Position
#1 A1     5        1
#2 B1   200        4
```